# Dynamic rescaling in d3.js has weird artifacts in gridlines

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I'm trying to create a plot in D3 that has a scale that I can adjust using a slider. It seems like it is failing slightly; the gridlines have artifacts when I readjust the scale.

Any idea what I am doing wrong? I have a slider with an `onChange` method that calls  `ysc.domain([0,this.value]);` to rescale the y-axis and it redraws the graph including the axis ticks and the gridlines.

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.8.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {


var margin = {top: 10, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 30},
width = 600,
height = 180;


// add the graph canvas to the body of the webpage
var svg = d3.select("div#plot1").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height);

var axis = svg.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var  xsc= d3.scaleLinear().domain([0,1]).range([0, width-margin.left-margin.right]),
  ysc= d3.scaleLinear().domain([0,1]).range([height-margin.top-margin.bottom,0]); 
  
var N = 500;  
axis.append("path");
var line = d3.line()
.x(function(d,i) { return  xsc(i/N); })
.y(function(d,i) { return  ysc(d); });
var axis_drawn = d3.axisLeft(  ysc );
axis.call( axis_drawn);
function drawGridLines ()
  {
 var grid=axis.selectAll("line.horizontalGrid");
 grid.data( ysc.ticks( )).enter()
  .append("line")
    .attr('class','horizontalGrid')
    .attr('x1',margin .right)
    .attr('x2',width)
    .attr('fill','none')
    .attr( "shape-rendering" , "crispEdges")
    .attr( "stroke" , "black")
    .attr("stroke-width" , "1px")
    .attr('opacity','0.2')
  .merge(grid)
    .attr('y1', ysc)
    .attr('y2', ysc);

 grid.exit().remove();   
  }      
function drawGraph()
{
var data = [];
var ylim = ysc.domain();
for (var i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
    data.push((Math.cos(i*8*Math.PI/N) + 1)/2.0);
}

var waveform = axis.selectAll("path");
waveform.datum(data)
.attr("fill","none")
.attr("stroke","steelblue")
.attr("d",  line);


axis.call( axis_drawn);
drawGridLines();
}
drawGraph();
function showRange(x) {
  d3.select('#rangeLabel').text(x);
} 
showRange(1);
d3.select('#range')
  .on('change', function(d) {
   ysc.domain([0,this.value]);
   drawGraph();
   showRange(this.value);
}); 


}); // DOMContentLoaded event
</script>
<style type='text/css'>
svg {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.grid line {
  stroke: lightgrey;
  stroke-opacity: 0.7;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.grid path {
  stroke-width: 0;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}  
div#interactive-container {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
}
form#interactive-controls {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}
div#plot2 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
}
</style>
</head><body>
<div id="plot1">
</div>
<div id='bottom-panel'>
<div id='interactive-container' class='hidden'>
<form id='interactive-controls'>
<input  type="range" id='range' value='1', min='1', max='10', step='1'><span id='rangeLabel'></span>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation isn't terribly clear on this, and I've got stuck on this before.

```
selection.data().enter()...
selection.exit()...
```

is not the same as:

```
selection.data();
selection.enter()...
selection.exit()...
```

We see .data().enter() chained often simply because all elements will be entered and none exited:

> what if we have no existing elements, such as with an empty page? Then
>   we’re joining data to an empty selection, and all data ends up in
>   enter.
>
> This pattern is so common, you’ll often see the selectAll + data +
>   enter + append methods called sequentially, one immediately after the
>   other. Despite it being common, keep in mind that this is just one
>   special case of a data join. ([Mike's three little circles](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/circles/)).

You're code works on initial append because all data ends up in the enter() selection anyways. No problems arise until the number of ticks exceeds 10, at which point the exit selection is evidently not working as anticipated whenever the number of ticks should decrease. It is empty and not removing anything. Using this setup:

```
selection.data();
selection.enter()...
selection.exit()...
```

should fix that:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.8.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {


var margin = {top: 10, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 30},
width = 600,
height = 180;


// add the graph canvas to the body of the webpage
var svg = d3.select("div#plot1").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height);

var axis = svg.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var  xsc= d3.scaleLinear().domain([0,1]).range([0, width-margin.left-margin.right]),
  ysc= d3.scaleLinear().domain([0,1]).range([height-margin.top-margin.bottom,0]); 
  
var N = 500;  
axis.append("path");
var line = d3.line()
.x(function(d,i) { return  xsc(i/N); })
.y(function(d,i) { return  ysc(d); });
var axis_drawn = d3.axisLeft(  ysc );
axis.call( axis_drawn);
function drawGridLines ()
  {
 var grid=axis.selectAll("line.horizontalGrid")
   .data( ysc.ticks() );
   
 grid.enter()
  .append("line")
    .attr('class','horizontalGrid')
    .attr('x1',margin .right)
    .attr('x2',width)
    .attr('fill','none')
    .attr( "shape-rendering" , "crispEdges")
    .attr( "stroke" , "black")
    .attr("stroke-width" , "1px")
    .attr('opacity','0.2')
  .merge(grid)
    .attr('y1', ysc)
    .attr('y2', ysc);

 grid.exit().remove();   
  }      
function drawGraph()
{
var data = [];
var ylim = ysc.domain();
for (var i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
    data.push((Math.cos(i*8*Math.PI/N) + 1)/2.0);
}

var waveform = axis.selectAll("path");
waveform.datum(data)
.attr("fill","none")
.attr("stroke","steelblue")
.attr("d",  line);


axis.call( axis_drawn);
drawGridLines();
}
drawGraph();
function showRange(x) {
  d3.select('#rangeLabel').text(x);
} 
showRange(1);
d3.select('#range')
  .on('change', function(d) {
   ysc.domain([0,this.value]);
   drawGraph();
   showRange(this.value);
}); 


}); // DOMContentLoaded event
</script>
<style type='text/css'>
svg {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.grid line {
  stroke: lightgrey;
  stroke-opacity: 0.7;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.grid path {
  stroke-width: 0;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}  
div#interactive-container {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
}
form#interactive-controls {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}
div#plot2 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
}
</style>
</head><body>
<div id="plot1">
</div>
<div id='bottom-panel'>
<div id='interactive-container' class='hidden'>
<form id='interactive-controls'>
<input  type="range" id='range' value='1', min='1', max='10', step='1'><span id='rangeLabel'></span>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks! could you elaborate as to why `selection.data().enter()...` is different than `selection.data(); selection.enter()...` ? I've read the three little circles and it doesn't make sense to me. So `selection.data()` doesn't return the selection itself?

Comment: oh, never mind, I get it now: https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_data -- selection.data([data[, key]]) --

Joins the specified array of data with the selected elements, returning a new selection that represents the update selection: the elements successfully bound to data.

Comment: I probably can provide a good answer on that - though I'd want to use a few snippets and there are also more capable d3 answerers than myself on SO that might provide something better if it was posted as a new question.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44597178/when-to-use-selection-data-something-vs-selection-merge-something-in