# When to use selection.data(...).something() vs. selection.merge().something() in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm confused about the difference between UPDATE and MERGE in d3 when [new data is joined](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/) to a selection.

ENTER is easy; it applies to new elements.

EXIT is easy; it applies to elements that were in the old data.

How do I know when to use UPDATE  vs. MERGE?

```
var thingies = d3.selectAll('.mythingy')
thingies.data(newData).call(handle_update)  // UPDATE
  .enter().call(handle_enter)               // ENTER
  .merge().call(handle_merge)               // MERGE
  .exit().call(handle_exit)                 // EXIT
```

?

Comment: You're always going to use update, so the question is more "when to merge"? You merge when you want to apply the same logic to the `enter` and `update` selections. Sometimes, you want to handle the `enter` selection differently, before merging with `update`. In your link, mike applies `.attr("r", 2.5)` to the enter selection, and THEN merges with the update. The update selection already had `.attr("r", 2.5)` applied.

Comment: First of all, there is no *update Vs merge*. The `merge` was created to remove a "magic" introduced in D3 v2. Have a look at this example in the S.O. docs: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/d3.js/5749/update-pattern/24929/merging-selections#t=201706162120068208209

Answer (score 2):

TLDR: update refers conceptually to a group of elements; `.merge()` is a method that can be used to combine the enter and update selections.

Update is a concept referring to the DOM elements that were in the DOM before the data change and remain there after the data change (i.e., the middle section of the Venn diagram in the link). There is no `.update()` method, however -- you get your update selection with `.selectAll()`.

This can lead to some redundancy where you are applying the same attributes/styles to elements that just entered (the `.enter()` selection) and were already there. The `.merge()` method introduced in D3v4 provides a solution where you get a selection of both your enter and update elements.

It is still possible to carry out the update process without using `.merge()`, and there are some cases where it might still make sense to write separate statements for the enter and update selections.